# Scientific notation when exporting SQL to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, scientific-notation

I have a SQL statement which is exporting data to Excel. The problem is that large numbers get converted to scientific notation when exported to Excel. To avoid that I am using char(39), i.e. single quotes around the number. In addition, also checking for null value so using `ISNULL`.

```
ISNULL(char(39) + Rtrim([NumberCol]) + char(39), '')
```

`[NumberCol]` has `char` datatype

So now if NumberCol is a numeric value I get '000123456789' format which is what I want. But when it is Null then I get ''. I do not want to display '' in Excel rather blank. Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: get rid of `ISNULL`

Answer (score 0):

The results when `null` are in the right part of the function. You are specifying the two tick marks as your returned value if `NumberCol` is `Null`:

```
ISNULL(char(39) + Rtrim([NumberCol]) + char(39), '')
```

If you don't want the two tick marks, you can use a space with char(32):

```
ISNULL(char(39) + Rtrim([NumberCol]) + char(39), char(32))
```

Visually, the space will look like an empty cell in Excel.

Comment: didn't fix the issue. The tick marks are due to char(39) around NumberCol

Comment: The tick marks by themselves can only show up if NumberCol is not null and does not have a number in it. Is it possible NumberCol does not have a numeric data type? In that case, when it is an empty string the tick marks could show up by themselves. If NumberCol is not numeric, this would work: `select isnull(char(39)+nullif([NumberCol],'')+char(39),char(32))`